# I installed Ubuntu on my parents computer. Besides SCP, is there a lazy way to drag and drop movies from my computer to theirs?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, remote-desktop, scp, nautilus

I installed Ubuntu on my parents computer. Besides SCP, is there a lazy way to drag and drop movies from my computer to theirs?

Should I use a virtual desktop? maybe a nautilus plugin or maybe scp gui client? What's the laziest way you know.

Comment: Set up an FTP server on their network, then use FileZilla on your computer to connect to the server and transfer files from your computer to theirs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mount ssh in nautilus.

1. Do `sudo apt-get install
   openssh-server` in your parents'
   computer and `sudo apt-get install
   openssh-client` in your computer.
2. Then go to **Ubuntu Menu -> Places -> Connect to server**, select **SSH** for service type and fill the information for the server IP and username. Look here for an screenshot of the window.

Then you can drag-and-drop from nautilus.

Answer (score 3):

if you're both on the same LAN (network) you could mount your drive (on the other PC) either via NFS or samba (windows file sharing) and then use nautilus file explorer to copy in between as the mount point will be seen as a "regular" folder.

Comment: Or even via SSHFS ;)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at `rsync` it works a little like scp but will sync whole directories. You could use something like this to move the files:

```
rsync -av ~/Videos parent-computer:Videos
```

This will move all of the files in the directory "Videos" in your home directory to the same location on their machine

Because of the way it's designed you can interrupt it at any time and it'll pick up where it was stopped. Or if you add new videos on your computer it'll just sync over the new/changed ones next time you run it.

Answer (score 1):

Share a [Dropbox](http://db.tt/oAbJPzL) directory. It will work seamlessly with whatever OS and GUI file manager you use, and regardless of what inbound ports your firewalls have blocked.

Comment: trouble is he mentioned "movies" so i'm guessing around 600MB each -- which will make it difficult to share more than 2-3 with the standard dropbox at 2Gb. Good idea though.

Comment: So just delete it when you're done watching. The OP will still have a local copy.

Comment: This is a pretty slow and inefficient way of doing things in comparison to a local network copy as you have to copy the files up to Dropbox's site and then back down again.

Comment: OP never said it was local...

Comment: (And if it is, Dropbox will detect it, and use it.)

Comment: @Alex: Only if "Enable LAN sync" is enabled on *both* computers.

Answer (score 1):

If you're already using SSH to copy files, why not use SSHFS? Just install the package sshfs-fuse.

The commands to mount an sshfs filesystem are a little too complicated for me to memorize, so I just set up a few aliases instead:

```
alias lserverfs='sshfs max@192.168.0.103:/home/max ~/server -o idmap=user -o uid=1000 -o gid=1000'
alias unmountserver='fusermount -u ~/server'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a cross-crimped LAN cable and connected the LAN ports of both computers. You can then create a [two-computer LAN network](http://www.vsubhash.com/article.asp?id=13&info=Ubuntu_and_Gnome_Diary#crossover_lan_cable_network_linux) by manually assigning IP address to both computers and use Nautilus to copy the files. Copying over LAN is usually faster.

Answer (score 1):

The legendary 'mc' is the best for such tasks.

[image]